# extend the lists by the same index on 2nd dimention

Tags: python, list, indexing, extend

I would like to find out how to extend the list by the same index. such as
A is shape (2,3,2). B is shape (2,5,2). I want to get C with shape as (2,8,2).
Thanks.

```
A=[[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], [[6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9]]]
B=[[[11, 12], [12, 13]], [[16, 17], [17, 18]]]
```

I want to get

```
[[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4],[11, 12], [12, 13]],
 [[6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [16, 17], [17, 18]]]
```

Comment: Example like this:A = [[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]],[[6,7], [7,8], [8,9]]]  B = [[[11,12], [12,13]],[[16,17], [17,18]]]. I want to get c=C= [[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [11,12], [12,13]], 
    [[[6,7], [7,8], [8,9], [16,17], [17,18]]]. Thanks

Comment: Please put your example directly in your question, that makes it easier for others to understand on the first view.

Comment: I am not sure how to make it looks nicer in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Use three backticks for code blocks or indent everything with four spaces or consult the formatting help displayed as a question mark in the upper right corner of the editor.

Comment: Thanks. I hope this make a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using np.hstack((a,b)). Where a and b are the np.array of A and B.
Then convert it back to a list. Thanks for your time.